# ユーザーのアクティビティ一覧で、種別用のカラム幅が一文字分しかなく、日時がはみ出ることがある

Tags: バグ, 完了, デザイン

URL例:  
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/30/ento?tab=activity  
https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/30/ento?tab=votes

[image: アクティビティのラベル]

「5時間」がはみ出ています:

[image: 「時間」だとはみ出る]

Comment: 時間がはみ出ている場合もあったので、追加しました

Comment: 現在デザインが非常に混雑しているため、少々時間がかかっています。しばらくお待ちください。

Comment: 2021-04 現在、[関連メタの不具合修正](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3548) と合わせてこの問題も修正されました。