# 日本語を含む UI の一部デザインが崩れて表示される

Tags: バグ, 完了, デザイン

日本語を含むUIが複数個所で表示が崩れてしまっています。これらの問題が起きている箇所は、元の英語の文字列よりも短いにも関わらずオーバーフローを起こしているように見えます。

(目についたものを挙げただけなので、これら以外の場所でも問題が起きている可能性があります)

```
search
検索

delete
削除

edit
編集
```

**キーワードでの検索結果画面に表示される「検索」ボタン**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**モデレーターツール画面の操作ボタン**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

なお、関連質問に挙げたアクティビティの部分ですが、例えばロシア語版では英語表記よりも長い文字列にも関わらず正常に表示されています。

**参考: ロシア語版でのユーザーアクティビティ**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

原因の一つとして考えられるのは、英語等は "Arial" フォントで表示される一方、日本語のみ "Meiryo" が使われており、このフォントの違いによって(日本語環境でのみ)デザイン崩れが起きている可能性があります。

**関連:**
[ユーザーのアクティビティ一覧で、種別用のカラム幅が一文字分しかなく、日時がはみ出ることがある](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/99)

Comment: 類似の動作として、質問文を書いているときに表示される「類似の質問」ボックス内のタイトル横の「回答」というテキストの折り返しも不自然ですね。

Comment: I'll add this to be addressed as part of our regular bug duty rotation. Thanks for the report!（こちらを通常のバグデューティローテーションに追加し対処いたします。ご報告ありがとうございます！ ）

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ご報告ありがとうございます！

いくつか修正を行いました：

- 検索バーを削除すると検索ページの問題が修正されました（検索バーは引き続きトップバーから使用可能です）
- モデレーターの通報アクションとユーザーアクティビティページの説明が折り返されなくなりました
- ユーザープロファイルのモデレーター専用「mod」リンクも折り返されなくなりました

こちらをもって [完了](/questions/tagged/%e5%ae%8c%e4%ba%86) とさせていただきますが、もしも折り返されるべきではない文字列が他にも見つかりましたらどうぞお教えくださいませ。修正いたします。

Comment: レビューキューの画面で一部おかしい部分が残っているようです。例: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqoBy.png