# タグ一覧ページの件数表示が見づらいのを改善したい

Tags: 討議, 完了, 翻訳

[タグの一覧ページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags) でそれぞれ割り当てられた質問の件数が表示されますが、日本語版だと文字が密集してしまい見づらいです。
[関連質問](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3206) で挙げたフォントの違いによる影響もありそうですが、原文に対しての翻訳文字列が長すぎる気もします。
(`n 件の質問 (今週)` は試しに少しだけ弄ってみましたが、全角1文字分しか違いが出ませんでした)

**現状の翻訳**

```
英: N asked today, N this week
日: N 件の今日の質問数, N 件の今週の質問数
```

---

**改善案**

改善案として、タグが割り当てられるのは「質問」だけなので、"質問数" の文字列を削る方法が挙げられます。

```
英: N asked today, N this week
日: N 件 (今日), N 件 (今週)
```

補足として、マウスオーバーすればツールチップで何の数字なのかの説明が表示されます (気づく人がいるのかは疑問ですが…)。

---

**日本語版**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**英語版**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**マウスオーバー時のツールチップ表示**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: MSE にて類似の改善案が挙げられているようです。 - [Can we improve tags filter cards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343563)

Answer (score 3):

「N 件 (今週), N 件 (今月)」でサイトに反映されましたことをご報告いたします。
[image]