# レビュータスクの回答数に関するテキストが枠線からはみ出している

Tags: バグ, デザイン, レビュー

つい最近レビュー周辺のデザインが変わりましたが、次の画像からわかるように、レビュータスクの回答数に関するテキストが緑色の枠線からはみ出してしまっています。また「回答」という1つの単語が1文字ずつ改行されており、読みづらいです。

[image: レビュータスクのスクリーンショット。「回答」という文字が1文字おきに改行されており、そのせいで緑色の枠線からはみ出していることがわかる]

この部分は次の画像のようになっていたほうが読みやすいと感じます。

[image: 前述した問題の改善案。「回答」という文字が1行に収まっており、枠線からもはみ出していない。]

Comment: 関連: [日本語を含む UI の一部デザインが崩れて表示される](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3206)

Comment: 恐らく日本語フォント固有の問題として 6～7年前から随所で発生しているので、スタッフさんや MSE に強めにアピールしないと治らないですね。