# Saves のプライベートメモ編集時の UI が崩れて表示される

Tags: バグ, 調査中, デザイン

自身のプロフィールページから保存済み Saves の一覧を閲覧時、メニューから「プライベートメモ」を残す機能がありますが、編集時の「保存」と「キャンセル」の文字列が崩れて表示されます。

過去の関連質問と同じく、日本語フォントの環境でのみ発生する問題が再発していると思われます。

**関連:**
[日本語を含む UI の一部デザインが崩れて表示される](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3206/3060)

**日本語版での表示:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**MSE (英語環境) での表示:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 5):

過去にも有ったようなので、担当の方はご理解いただいていると思いますが、念のため書いておきますと、この原因は日本語の折り返し規則にあります。日本語は、行の折り返し時に単語を考慮せず、一文字単位で分割してよい言語です。ブラウザの表示もデフォルトではこの規則に従います。

これに対処するには、CSS で該当の要素に `white-space: nowrap;` や `word-break: keep-all;` のように指定します。StackOverflow ではこれを行なう [`ws-nowrap` クラス](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/blob/0fb06231f966e5df7bb24c2d6d3979c1e0687481/lib/css/atomic/typography.less#L182)が有るようなので、これを該当の要素に追加することになると思います。